# Kentico - Bynder integration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, kentico, kentico-mvc

I'm using Kentico 13 .NET Core and want to integrate with Bynder

https://github.com/Kentico/xperience-module-bynder

https://www.kentico.com/discover/blog/powerful-integrations-kentico-xperience-13-refresh

It works fine with the page types and I can see the new form control under the form control selection but how do I use it in a widget in the .NET core MVC app?

Ex:
I want to replace this UrlSelector component with the Bynder component. How do I do that?

```
[EditingComponent(UrlSelector.IDENTIFIER, Order = 5, Label = "Image Slider Selector")]
[EditingComponentProperty(nameof(UrlSelectorProperties.Tabs), ContentSelectorTabs.Page)]
public string ImageSliderSelector { get; set; }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "integration" is only with the page type selector. There are no other controls. You have to make those on your own. This would mean you'd need one for the CKEditor and the Froala editor as well.

Comment: is there anything we can find in the market place? We chose Bynder as our DAM solution, because we were told by Kentico that it integrates in Bynder but now it looks like only half done.

Comment: Look around the marketplace and see what you find.  The integration is there, however, it is only for a page type field.  If you want further, you'd have to build that out to your specifications.